# Wordpress cached page won't load. W3 Total Cache + Nginx

Tags: wordpress, nginx, gzip, w3-total-cache

So I am having an issue, when I navigate to a page of my site after it is cached it just downloads a nameless file. (When I did this on my iPhone it called it the name of the site plus .gz) Thus I am assuming that gzip is having issues from the total cache setup. Looking for thoughts around a fix. Thank you!

EDIT: Seems to be the `set $w3tc_enc _gzip;` line. I disable that and it will work. But still not sure why.

It used to work just fine and I am just using the standard code total cache gave me in my domain's config file:

```
# BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core
set $w3tc_rewrite 1;
if ($request_method = POST) {
    set $w3tc_rewrite 0;
}
if ($query_string != "") {
    set $w3tc_rewrite 0;
}
if ($request_uri !~ \/$) {
    set $w3tc_rewrite 0;
}
if ($http_cookie ~* "(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in)") {
    set $w3tc_rewrite 0;
}
set $w3tc_enc "";
if ($http_accept_encoding ~ gzip) {
    set $w3tc_enc _gzip;
}
if (!-f "$document_root/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/$http_host/$request_uri/_index.html$w3tc_enc") {
  set $w3tc_rewrite 0;
}
if ($w3tc_rewrite = 1) {
    rewrite .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/$http_host/$request_uri/_index.html$w3tc_enc" last;
}
# END W3TC Page Cache core
```

Answer (score 0):

Either I enabled a new feature that needed more config options, or the last time I made an update it added these as a requirement as it worked when I switched to this in the config.

```
# BEGIN W3TC Page Cache cache
location ~ /wp-content/cache/page_enhanced.*html$ {
    add_header X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.3";
    add_header Vary "Accept-Encoding, Cookie";
}
location ~ /wp-content/cache/page_enhanced.*gzip$ {
    gzip off;
    types {}
    default_type text/html;
    add_header X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.3";
    add_header Vary "Accept-Encoding, Cookie";
    add_header Content-Encoding gzip;
}
# END W3TC Page Cache cache
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
gzip on;
gzip_types text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon;
location ~ \.(css|htc|js|js2|js3|js4)$ {
    add_header X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.3";
}
location ~ \.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml)$ {
    add_header X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.3";
}
location ~ \.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|json|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$ {
    add_header X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.3";
}
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core
set $w3tc_rewrite 1;
if ($request_method = POST) {
    set $w3tc_rewrite 0;
}
if ($query_string != "") {
    set $w3tc_rewrite 0;
}
if ($request_uri !~ \/$) {
    set $w3tc_rewrite 0;
}
if ($http_cookie ~* "(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in)") {
    set $w3tc_rewrite 0;
}
set $w3tc_enc "";
if ($http_accept_encoding ~ gzip) {
    set $w3tc_enc _gzip;
}
if (!-f "$document_root/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/$http_host/$request_uri/_index.html$w3tc_enc") {
  set $w3tc_rewrite 0;
}
if ($w3tc_rewrite = 1) {
    rewrite .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/$http_host/$request_uri/_index.html$w3tc_enc" last;
}
# END W3TC Page Cache core
```